# How can I group optional attributes captured with syntax-parse?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

When writing a macro that uses `syntax/parse`, I have created a splicing syntax class that captures options that may be provided to the macro. These options are all optional, and they may be provided in any order. Using the `~optional` ellipsis head pattern makes this easy enough:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class opts
  (pattern (~seq (~or (~optional (~seq #:a a))
                      (~optional (~seq #:b b))
                      (~optional (~seq #:x x))
                      (~optional (~seq #:y y)))
                 ...))
```

However, there is a catch: I want to be able to *group* these options into two groups: the group containing `a` and `b`, and the group containing `x` and `y`. However, the user may still specify the options in any order, so for this example input:

```
(foobar #:b 3 #:y 7 #:a 2)
```

I want to be able to produce the following attributes:

```
first-opts:  (#:a 2 #:b 3)
second-opts: (#:y 7)
```

So far, I’ve managed to do this manually using `#:with`, but it isn’t pretty:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class opts
  #:attributes ([first-opts 1] [second-opts 1])
  (pattern (~seq (~or (~optional (~seq #:a a))
                      (~optional (~seq #:b b))
                      (~optional (~seq #:x x))
                      (~optional (~seq #:y y)))
                 ...)
           #:with (first-opts ...)
           #`(#,@(if (attribute a) #'(#:a a) #'())
              #,@(if (attribute b) #'(#:b b) #'()))
           #:with (second-opts ...)
           #`(#,@(if (attribute x) #'(#:x x) #'())
              #,@(if (attribute y) #'(#:y y) #'()))))
```

This can be simplified a little bit using `template` from `syntax/parse/experimental/template`:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class opts
  #:attributes ([first-opts 1] [second-opts 1])
  (pattern (~seq (~or (~optional (~seq #:a a))
                      (~optional (~seq #:b b))
                      (~optional (~seq #:x x))
                      (~optional (~seq #:y y)))
                 ...)
           #:with (first-opts ...)
           (template ((?? (?@ #:a a))
                      (?? (?@ #:b b))))
           #:with (second-opts ...)
           (template ((?? (?@ #:a x))
                      (?? (?@ #:b y))))))
```

However, this is really just some sugar for the above, and it doesn’t actually address the problem of having to enumerate each option in each clause. If I, for example, added a `#:c` option, I would need to remember to add it to the `first-opts` group, otherwise it would be completely ignored.

What I *really* want is some declarative way to group these sets of optional values. For example, I’d like a syntax like this:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class opts
  #:attributes ([first-opts 1] [second-opts 1])
  (pattern (~seq (~or (~group first-opts
                              (~optional (~seq #:a a))
                              (~optional (~seq #:b b)))
                      (~group second-opts
                              (~optional (~seq #:x x))
                              (~optional (~seq #:y y))))
                 ...)))
```

Or, even better, it would be nice if I could use existing primitives, something like this:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class opts
  #:attributes ([first-opts 1] [second-opts 1])
  (pattern (~seq (~or (~and first-opts
                            (~seq (~optional (~seq #:a a))
                                  (~optional (~seq #:b b))))
                      (~and second-opts
                            (~seq (~optional (~seq #:x x))
                                  (~optional (~seq #:y y)))))
                 ...)))
```

However, neither of those work. Is there any way to do this using the builtins provided by `syntax/parse`? If not, is there any simple way to define something like `~group` myself?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do that with a `~groups-no-order` pattern expander like this:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class opts
  #:attributes ([first-opts 1] [second-opts 1])
  [pattern (~groups-no-order
            [first-opts
             (~optional (~seq #:a a))
             (~optional (~seq #:b b))]
            [second-opts
             (~optional (~seq #:x x))
             (~optional (~seq #:y y))])])

(syntax-parse #'(foobar #:b 3 #:y 7 #:a 2)
  [(foobar opts:opts)
   (values #'(opts.first-opts ...)
           #'(opts.second-opts ...))])
; #<syntax (#:a 2 #:b 3)>
; #<syntax (#:y 7)>
```

Where `~groups-no-order` can be defined like this:

```
#lang racket
(provide ~groups-no-order)

(require syntax/parse
         seq-no-order
         (for-syntax racket/syntax
                     syntax/stx))

(define-syntax ~groups-no-order
  (pattern-expander
   (lambda (stx)
     (syntax-case stx ()
       [(groups [group-name member-pat ...] ...)
        (with-syntax ([ooo (quote-syntax ...)])
          (define/with-syntax [[member-tmp ...] ...]
            (stx-map generate-temporaries #'[[member-pat ...] ...]))
          (define/with-syntax [group-tmp ...]
            (generate-temporaries #'[group-name ...]))
          #'(~and (~seq-no-order (~and (~seq (~var member-tmp) ooo)
                                       member-pat)
                                 ... ...)
                  (~parse [[(~var group-tmp) ooo] ooo] #'[[member-tmp ooo] ...])
                  ...
                  (~parse [group-name ooo] #'[group-tmp ooo ooo])
                  ...))]))))
```

This does the same thing as your first solution using `#:with`, but it abstracts that stuff out into a reusable pattern expander.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not (yet) sure of a way you can do this with something like `~group`, but there is a way you can make your existing (working) solution that uses `#:with` look a lot nicer. Maybe it will work for your case, maybe not.

[`~optional`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html?q=~optional#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._~7eoptional%29%29) takes in a default argument `#:defaults`, which you can set to be the empty syntax list, `#'#f`, or some other sentinel value, removing your requirement to have an `if` statement in your `#:with` clause.  It would look something like this:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class opts
  #:attributes ([first-opts 1] [second-opts 1])
  (pattern (~seq (~or (~optional (~seq #:a a) #:defaults ([a #'#f]))
                      (~optional (~seq #:b b) #:defaults ([b #'#f]))
                      (~optional (~seq #:x x) #:defaults ([x #'#f]))
                      (~optional (~seq #:y y) #:defaults ([y #'#f])))
                 ...)
           #:with (first-opts ...) #'(#:a a #:b b)
           #:with (second-opts ...) #'(#:x x #:y y)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me because I don’t have a default value to use—I need the keyword arguments that aren’t provided to *not* show up in the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `~and` leads to the most straightforward macro, but the head pattern version of `~and` is more restrictive and doesn't quite work so I would separate the head-pattern part out.

Does the code below accomplish what you want?

Without head patterns you lose `~optional` so I manually check for duplicates.

Also, `first-opts` and `second-opts` are not flattened, but I suspect that is ok?

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse racket/list))

(define-for-syntax (check-duplicate-kws kws-stx)
  (check-duplicates (syntax->list kws-stx) #:key syntax->datum))

(define-syntax test
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ (~seq k:keyword v) ...)
     #:fail-when (check-duplicate-kws #'(k ...)) "duplicate keyword"
     #:with ((~or (~and first-opts (~or (#:a _) (#:b _)))
                  (~and second-opts (~or (#:c _) (#:d _)))) ...)
            #'((k v) ...)
     #'(void)]))
```